# Certwizard error codenameone

Tags: codenameone

I have an app developed with the codename plugin in netbeans , but when trying to use the certificate wizard not up causing the attached error could tell me what could be causing this failure. [Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B5NdZ.png)

Comment: https://groups.google.com/d/msgid/codenameone-discussions/CAGOYrKXSjYRDu7YTR3SHpStGvVxn9-i%2BFzt%2B0FKa4dgYFH2G%2BQ%40mail.gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

If I remember correctly, that wizard doesn't work with NetBeans. It works with Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

You need to be connected to the internet to use the certificate wizard. You need to make sure that proxies are configured globally for Java. The main reason for that is that the certificate wizard needs to connect to Apples servers so there is no sense in it working offline.

Answer (score 0):

the error was on my side , but on the mac had internet connection and configurations netbeans and java pointed to my right proxy , there was a problem locking level firewall proxy , which has already been corrected , thank you very much .